# Drawing a square by dragging the mouse

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a Java program that closely mimics Microsoft Paint. It can draw four different shapes: Lines, Ovals, Rectangles, and Squares. I am very close to finishing this but I am stuck on the logic for drawing squares.

There are two Points involved while drawing these shapes. The first Point(point1) is when the user presses the mouse button and the second Point(point2) is while the user drags the mouse across the canvas. I believe drawing Rectangles and Squares should be quite similar but the part that has confused me is when drawing a square the sides are equal length so point2 isn't exactly where the mouse is.

Here is the fillRect() method header for reference:

```
fillRect(x, y, width, height)
```

My functioning code for drawing rectangles is as follows:

```
g.fillRect((((point1.x < point2.x) ? point1.x : point2.x)),
            ((point1.y < point2.y) ? point1.y : point2.y), 
            Math.abs(point2.x - point1.x), 
            Math.abs(point2.y - point1.y));
```

I tried using the same code for drawing squares except changing the height parameter to be equal to the width parameter because squares have equal length sides:

```
g.fillRect((((point1.x < point2.x) ? point1.x : point2.x)), 
            ((point1.y < point2.y) ? point1.y : point2.y), 
            Math.abs(point2.x - point1.x), 
            Math.abs(point2.x - point1.x)); //same as width
```

I don't know what the problem is with making both width and height equal. It works when drawing downwards to the left or right but of course the shape does not expand if you pull straight down. Clicking and dragging up does not work; the square simply moves up with the mouse along the Y axis instead of expanding.

Could anyone point me in the right direction regarding the logic for drawing square from two points?

I can explain my code a bit better if need be.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You should do two calculations in your MouseDragged method -- first you should calculate the two corner Points of the rectangle, p1, and p2, and only then should you calculate the width. Point p1 is easy -- it's always the first Point pressed, but p2 will require a simple calculation. Once these are clarified, your calculations should fall out correctly.

i.e., something like:

```
  int width = Math.abs(pointA.x - pointB.x);
  int height = Math.abs(pointA.y - pointB.y);

  width = Math.max(width, height);
  height = width;

  int x = pointA.x > pointB.x ? pointA.x - width : pointA.x;
  int y = pointA.y > pointB.y ? pointA.y - width : pointA.y;

  g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were using a tool to draw a square, I would expect that my mouse cursor would remain on one of the sides of the square while drawing.  If you always use the x distance as the side, then if I've drawn farther down than across, the cursor will be outside the square.

I think, while the dragging is going on, the code would need to calculate whether the x distance or the y distance to the origin is the longer, and use that as the side of the square-in-progress.  Then the cursor will be on one of the sides, and that side will extend out beyond the cursor to the corner of the square-in-progress.

I don't know why the drawing is going awry -- it is difficult to be sure I understand what you say is going wrong.